# Executing 6 SQL statements in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

To achieve my target table, the only way i came out with is through 6 SQL statements. And they have to be executed in sequence, meaning 1 then 2 then 3.....6. In the process, i make use of 5 so called 'temp/residents tables'. Is there any in SSIS?I would just like to know if i can reuse this 6 statements in SSIS. Meaning a process flow to run this 6 statements. Is it possible? If so, mind guiding me how? What to include in Control flow and what to have in data flow?

Thanks,
10e5x

Comment: Do you already have these temp tables created or do they need to be created on the fly? Whats the complexity you are facing here?

Comment: i guess its on the fly. for e.g sql1 will derive temp1 and sql2 will use temp1 to derive 2...sql6 wll then use temp5 to derive my target table. Any advice?

Comment: Check the CTE example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are over complicating the issue, you can put all 6 statements into a single "Execute SQL Task" Control flow item, OR you could put them all into a single Stored Procedure with the SQL statements in the correct order and execute that via an "Execute SQL Task".

Personally I'd put them into a Stored Procedure.

Data Flows are for Data, i.e. moving chunks of data around and Control Flows are to control the sequence of operations one or more of which may be Data Flows.

Comment: V.true SSIS does not like temp tables. BUT only if you want them to persist between tasks. It is eminently doable of course just messy. However the nowhere did I suggest trying to persist temp tables between tasks. If the OP puts his script into a single SQL Task it will work just fine.

Comment: Good point, which was why I agreed about a Stored Proc.  Thanks for clarifying my point.

Comment: Hi all, all of your solutions sounds very logical. So i think i shall put them in stored procedure. Currently the temp tables are created on the fly, for e.g sql1 will derive temp1 and sql2 will use temp1 to derive temp2. How shall i optimize this kind of flow in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the 6 interdependent SQL statements into one using **Common Table Expressions**. For e.g. I have shown just 3 tables, C1, C2, C3 and a final select statement. Don't forget the semi-colon at the end.

```
WITH C1 AS
(
  SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3
  FROM Table1
),
C2 AS
(
  SELECT Col1, count(Col1) as numOfCol1
  FROM C1
  GROUP BY Col1
),
C3 AS
(
  Select substring(Col1,1,10) as FirstName, substring(Col1,10,10) as LastName, numOfCol1
  FROM C2
),
SELECT *
FROM C3
WHERE numofCol1 > 10;
```